# Proving that a function is an increasing function

Tags: functions

Question:

"**5.** Functions f and g, with domains $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, are defined as follows:

$$\text{f}:x \to \sqrt{x}, \quad \text{g}:x \to 1 + 3x^{2}.$$

If the function h is defined by $h(x) = f(g(x))$, show that h is an increasing function and sketch its graph."

My approach was to find h:

$\text{h}(x) = \sqrt{1 + 3x^{2}}$

Then find $\text{h}'(x)$:

$\text{h}'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + 3x^{2}}} \cdot 6x = \dfrac{3x}{\sqrt{1 + 3x^{2}}}$

And then what I want to do is prove that $\text{h}'(x) > 0,\ \forall{}x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$; but I'm, uh, not really sure where to begin?

Comment: I didn't check if your $h'(x)$ is correct, but hint: is either of the denominator or the numerator negative when $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is alright, now set $\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}} \ge 0$. Note that the square root is always positive, so this comes down to $3x\ge 0 \implies x \ge 0$

**Note**: If you want to show that the function is strictly increasing then you should substitute $\ge$ with >

Comment: The domain of both $f$ and $g$ is $\mathbb R^+$, so $h'(x)>0$ over its entire domain.

Comment: @Jon Of course, but $h'(x) > 0 \implies h'(x) \ge 0$ ,right? Anyway the OP never mentioned that he wants to prove that the composition of the function is strictly increasing, instead he wants to prove that the composition is increasing, and proving that $h'(x) \ge 0$ is enough to prove that claim.

Comment: I was pointing out that a stronger statement could be made, which the OP asked for by explicitly writing "what I want to do is prove that $h′(x)>0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+$". Or didn't you read that far?

Comment: That's what he wants to prove, but the questions asks for a proof of an increasing function

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in \mathbb R^+$, we have $x > 0$ and it is easy to see that $3x > 0$.
Also, note that $x > 0 \implies 3x^2 > 0 \implies 1 + 3x^2 > 0 \implies \sqrt{1+3x^2} > 0$.
Then, both numerator and denominator are positive, and you can draw your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

So as you have found, $h'(x)=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1 + 3x^{2}}}$.

Now $x\in\Bbb{R}^+\Leftrightarrow x>0$.

The numerator, $3x$, is of the same sign as $x$, hence it's positive.

The denominator is a square root, and thus most be positive. As a result $h'(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $h$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

$3x \over \sqrt{3x^2+1}$ $> 0$ iff 3x > 0 since the denominator is always positive

Hence, h'(x) > 0 iff x > 0.

Since it is given that x > 0, it follows that h'(x) > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ and $g$ be increasing functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ show that the composite of the two functions $f.g $ wherever it is defined is increasing. Then show that $x \to \sqrt{x}$ and $x \to 1+3x^{2}$ are both increasing.

Also , To show that $f(x)=3x/ \sqrt{1+3x^{2}}$ is increasing , divide both the numerator and denominator by $x$ the result is $3/ \sqrt{3+1/x^{2}}$ which is always positive .